# No rep for question upvotes?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, private-beta, meta

I was just upvoted for a question on Meta, but there was no rep increase.

Comment: Indeed, doesn't work!

Comment: @Ivo, actually, if you click on recent activity it shows the rep, just isn't in the total.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no reputation awarded for posts in the "child" meta sites (i.e. meta.webapps.stackexchange.com). The "reputation" is *inherited* from the parent site. But you *will* get meta-specific badges, though.

Comment: It appears to be inherited from when you opened the meta account. Will it update periodically?

Comment: Though the badges aren't being awarded here either - http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26/badge-total-not-updating

Comment: @ChrisF: Reputation from the parent site is transferred to meta hourly.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that we won't have to put up with reputation hunters like the ones on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @kino meta has reputation hunters? news to me...

Comment: Um, OK then. It's often difficult to get a sensible response on meta.stackoverflow.com because of all the noise from people I had wildly assumed were reputation hunters. I thought that must be why there wasn't a separate reputation counter here, but maybe not.

Comment: Sarcasm is such a low form of wit that I fear it slips under the radar