# Why did I start with 138 rep here instead of 101?

Tags: support, reputation

Looking at other user's, I see that meta.webapps... rep isn't shared with webapps... since not everyone's rep is in synch.  What's going on here?

Comment: I think I started at 143 for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just saw Robert's answer to [this question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/no-rep-for-question-upvotes/28#28).  That answer, along with his comment to his own answer, answers this question.  Rep *is* shared with the "parent" site, but it's only updated every hour, so it may get out of synch.