# How do bounties work on WebApps meta?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, meta

It turns out you [can't get reputation](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/no-rep-for-question-upvotes/28#28) from the WebApps meta site and you presumably can't lose it either.

However, the WebApps meta still [has a featured tab,](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) so i'm wondering how bounties work on it. Is this a bug and it's impossible to start meta bounties, or can you still lose/gain rep from bounties on meta even though the same doesn't appy for upvotes?

Comment: My guess is that eventually this feature will be removed since it doesn't really make sense on meta sites.

Comment: From what i've seen on MSO people add a bounty when they want a moderator to at least comment on a suggestion that is important to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should remove the featured tab from child metas. You can't start a bounty here anyway.

(It's different for meta.so because that is indeed a standalone, governmental site -- the equivalent of Washington, D.C. in USA politics)

Comment: Retagged as bug.