# Rep hit for downvotes on meta.webapps

Tags: support, meta, reputation

Earlier today, I got two reputation hits from downvotes here on meta. I'm not particularly worried about the two rep points, but I was under the impression that downvotes on meta weren't supposed to cost the user rep. (See [this question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66092?tab=votes#tab-top).)

[image: Recent Activity]

What's going on here? Is this a problem, or am I misunderstanding the situation?

Comment: Are you sure that was the cause?

Comment: I think this should be edited to be a bug request because there is a display problem showing negative rep when actually there is no negative rep.

Comment: @Brian - I agree, it's deceptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta votes do not affect your rep.

> There is no reputation awarded for
>   posts in the "child" meta sites (i.e.
>   meta.webapps.stackexchange.com). The
>   "reputation" is inherited from the
>   parent site. But you will get
>   meta-specific badges, though
>   - [No rep for question upvotes?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/no-rep-for-question-upvotes/28#28)

You can check your webapps profile to add it up.
Did a quick add for you.
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/2942?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top

`101+40+30+20+20+5-4+20+15+10+10+5+5+8=285`
All questions and answers accounted for.

Answer (score 2):

They didn't cost you rep. Your reputation total is still the same as it is on the parent site.

I even voted down this question, see you're still at 285. The image is simply showing that you received down/up votes.